# C# Check if input is in the Pattern of A<INTEGER>

Tags: c#

Possible input :

1) ASDF-123-ZXCV-456

2) YUIO-123-BNNM-987

3) QWER-123-LKJH-111

4) A1234

5) A456

I  need find the input that matches a Pattern of  Axxx(integer), in this case,either 4) or 5) should be returned..

I tried startWith("A"), but  1) still returns since it also starts with A, but i don't want that

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about `A1B`? Should it be matched?

Comment: use a regular expression. Something like `^A\d+$`

Comment: No A1B shouldn't returned. Characters after A should be INTEGER only

Comment: Can you clarify if the integer part of the pattern is required?  Would just `"A"` be valid input?

Comment: Are negative integers allowed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extending @aleks-andreev's comment, you could try:

```
    bool IsLetterAThenNumericPattern(string candidate)
    {
        return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(candidate, @"^A\d+$");
    }
```

This will return `true` for cases like:

- A1
- A123
- A1234567890101

and false for cases like:

- B1
- A
- A12345A
- A123-456

The regex breaks down like this:

- `^` start at the beginning of the string
- `A` match only the letter A
- `\d+` match one or more than one digit
- `$` end of the string.

In summary, this regex returns true only if the string starts with the letter A and then is followed by >=1 digits, and nothing else.

Comment: awesome! Thank you

Comment: You forgot to add a link to [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jbiyxs/1/) :) Also, it would be awesome if you add some explanation to regex. For example: `^` means start of string  and so on.

Comment: Thanks @AleksAndreev - edited based on your feedback.

Comment: Mjames already wrote the answer. So, no point in writing this again: https://rextester.com/BSIZ40453

Answer (score 3):

Since it's a simple pattern you can also use Linq or `uint.TryParse`:

```
var inputs = new List<string>(){
    "ASDF-123-ZXCV-456",
    "YUIO-123-BNNM-987",
    "QWER-123-LKJH-111",
    "A1234",
    "A456",
    "A-456",
    "A 456",
    "A",
    "A1",
    ""
};
foreach(var input in inputs){
    //Linq
    bool isMatch = input.Length>0 && input[0]=='A' && input.Skip(1).All(x=>char.IsDigit(x));
    //tryparse
    bool isMatch2 = input.Length>0 && input[0]=='A' && uint.TryParse(input.Substring(1),NumberStyles.None,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,out _);   
}
```

If you want at least 1 digit after the letter 'A', you can replace `input.Length>0` for `input.Length>1` in both approaches

In my tests, the Linq is faster, followed by uint.TryParse and then Regex

Comment: Your LINQ approach incorrectly evaluates to `true` for the input `"A"` since `.Skip(1).All(...)` returns `true` for empty sequences.  Your `TryParse` approach incorrectly evaluates to `true` for the input `"A-1"` since it accepts negative integers.

Comment: @BACON about the Linq aproach OP didn't say anything about no digits after, but I can adapt if thats an issue. About tryparse I agree, will correct.

Comment: The title and body of the question say they want to match `'A'` followed by an integer, so it seems to me the integer part is required, even though none of their test cases cover that.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers provide more concise ways of doing this, but it's good to understand how you would accomplish this yourself.  Here's the conclusion of what you were attempting with `.StartsWith("A")`...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] inputs = new string[] {
        null,
        string.Empty,
        "A",
        "ASDF-123-ZXCV-456",
        "YUIO-123-BNNM-987",
        "QWER-123-LKJH-111",
        "A1234",
        "A456",
        "A789Z",
        "A000",
        "B000"
    };
    const int longestInputLength = 17;

    foreach (string input in inputs)
    {
        bool result = IsNonNegativeIntegerWithPrefix(input);

        Console.WriteLine($"{input,longestInputLength}: {result}");
    }
}

static bool IsNonNegativeIntegerWithPrefix(string text)
{
    const string prefix = "A";

    if (text == null)
    {
        // Alternative: throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(text));
        return false;
    }

    // There must be at least one additional character beyond the prefix
    if (text.Length < prefix.Length + 1)
        return false;

    // The string must start with the prefix
    if (!text.StartsWith(prefix))
        return false;

    // Every character after the prefix must be a digit
    for (int index = prefix.Length; index < text.Length; index++)
        if (!char.IsDigit(text[index]))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

...which outputs...

```
                 : False
                 : False
                A: False
ASDF-123-ZXCV-456: False
YUIO-123-BNNM-987: False
QWER-123-LKJH-111: False
            A1234: True
             A456: True
            A789Z: False
             A000: True
             B000: False
```

Note that the above code works with prefixes of any length, not just a single character.  I would have made `prefix` a method parameter, but I did not want handling when that parameter is `null` or empty to distract from the basic logic.